# Selected a row in a grid view, now want to update that record with update button click

Tags: asp.net, button, gridview, textbox

I have been stuck on this and tried a few different things to use the update button to update the record that I selected from the grid view. I have 2 columns in the table Id and Name. I select the record and it populates a text box with the name.... this works fine. I just need to take that same record and update the name from that same text box after it is pulled into the text box by using an update button click event. I have two other buttons that work just fine which are "Add" and "Delete" and I will add that code as well but here is the code:

This is how I have populated the grid view on page load or when I call the method:

```
private void PopulateCompanyListGrid() //This will populate the grid with the table data on page load
    {
        IList<Company> companies;

        using (var context = new IMSDBContext())
        {
            companies = context.Companies.ToList();
        }

        grdvwCompanyList.DataSource = companies;
        grdvwCompanyList.DataBind();
    }
```

This is how the grid view is set up:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdvwCompanyList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectGridRow" DataKeyNames="Id, Name" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"></asp:GridView>
```

This is how I put the selected record in the text box:

```
public void SelectGridRow(object sender, EventArgs e) //This will populate the textbo with the row selected from the gridview
    {
        GridViewRow name = grdvwCompanyList.SelectedRow;

        if (name != null)
        {
            var dataKey = grdvwCompanyList.DataKeys[name.RowIndex];
            if (dataKey != null)
                txtCompanyName.Text = (string)dataKey["Name"];


        }
    }
```

This is how I am adding records:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // This method adds a record to the database
    {
        if (btnAdd.Text == "Add") // Clears the textbox and notification label and calls method to change name of button if the button says "Add"
        {
            txtCompanyName.Text = "";
            lblCompanyNameNotification.Text = "";
            ButtonChangeAddToSave();
        }
        else if (btnAdd.Text == "Save") // Checks if the button says "Save" and compares textbox and database for a matching record 
        {
            IMSDBContext context = new IMSDBContext();
            Company CompanyCheck = context.Companies.SingleOrDefault(Company => Company.Name == txtCompanyName.Text);

            if (CompanyCheck != null) // Displays a notification if there is already a matching record
            {
                lblCompanyNameNotification.Text = "There is already a Company with that name.";
            }
            else if(txtCompanyName.Text == null)
            { 
                lblCompanyNameNotification.Text = "Please enter a name of a company";
            }
            else if (txtCompanyName.Text != null) // Write the record to the database if no matching record in the database
            {
                Company n = new Company();
                n.Name = txtCompanyName.Text.ToString();


                context.Companies.Add(n);
                context.SaveChanges();

                txtCompanyName.Text = "";
                lblCompanyNameNotification.Text = "";

                ButtonChangeSaveToAdd();
            }
        }
        PopulateCompanyListGrid(); // Calls method to repopulate the gridview
    }
```

Comment: Show your Update Method .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden field in the markup to hold company Id:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCompanyId" runat="server" ></asp:HiddenField>
```

In the selectGridRow method populate the hidden field with company Id:

```
public void SelectGridRow(object sender, EventArgs e) //This will populate the textbo with the row selected from the gridview
{
    GridViewRow name = grdvwCompanyList.SelectedRow;

    if (name != null)
    {
        var dataKeys = grdvwCompanyList.DataKeys[name.RowIndex];
        if (dataKeys["Name"] != null)
            txtCompanyName.Text = (string)dataKeys["Name"];
        if (dataKeys["Id"] != null)
            hdnCompanyId.Value = dataKeys["Id"].ToString();
    }
}
```

In the btnUpdate_Click method get the company by Id and update it :

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    int companyId;
    string companyName = txtCompanyName.Text;
    if(int.TryParse(hdnCompanyId.Value, out companyId)){

        IMSDBContext context = new IMSDBContext();
        Company company = context.Companies.SingleOrDefault(Company => Company.Id == companyId);

        if (company != null && txtCompanyName.Text != "")
        {
            company.Name = companyName;
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
        else
        {
            lblCompanyNameNotification.Text = "The  Company does not exist.";
        }
    }

    PopulateCompanyListGrid(); // Calls method to repopulate the gridview            
}
```

Comment: I posted this Friday right before I went home for the weekend and was stumped for a minute being confused on how to bind the name to the selection made in the grid view. On the way to work this morning it dawned on me that I needed to do exactly what you posted. I had it in my head what I needed to do and I came in first thing and saw your post. At least I know that I was headed in the right direction when I came in this morning. Thank you for the help.